# Wordpress Page Buttons

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have uploaded buttons to my front page in WordPress.org.  When you click on one of the buttons it takes you to another page.  all the buttons work perfectly.  However, I would like to create the effect of the button actually being pressed when clicked on.  What would be the best approach to create this effect in WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `:active`

```
.myBtn:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/cU4Q7/)

Comment: I spaced out.  The first button code is, <a title="Produtos Cuidados e Beleza" href="http://eggertenterprises.net/produtos-beleza/"><img class="wp-image-837 aligncenter" alt="BlkButtonWorld_CuidadosBeleza" src="http://eggertenterprises.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/BlkButtonWorld_CuidadosBeleza-300x97.jpg" width="300" height="97" /></a>

Comment: I am new to web development.  How would I incorporate the active into html?

Comment: add `.textwidget a:active { position:relative; top:3px; }` to your `style.css` or specify a class for your `<a>` tags e.g. `<a class="sidebar-permalink">`, anyways, both solutions will work